# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration~~~~ error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am working on java spring shopping mall project. I want to fix this error.

Below is my code.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4768b95c testClass = com.maven_shopping.repository.ItemRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [com.maven_shopping.MavenShoppingApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = ["classpath:application-test.properties"], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4e268090, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5939a379, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1f97cf0d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@44821a96, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@9346081e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

Item.java:

```
package com.maven_shopping.entity;

import com.maven_shopping.constant.ItemSellStatus;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String itemName;
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private int price;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int stockNum;
    @Lob
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String itemDetail;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ItemSellStatus itemSellStatus;
    private LocalDateTime regTime;
    private LocalDateTime updateTime;
}
```

ItemRepositoryTest :

```
package com.maven_shopping.repository;

import com.maven_shopping.constant.ItemSellStatus;
import com.maven_shopping.entity.Item;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.\*;

@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
class ItemRepositoryTest {
@Autowired
ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("상품 저장 테스트")
    public void createItemTest() {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setItemName("Test Product");
        item.setPrice(10000);
        item.setItemDetail("Test Product Detail");
        item.setItemSellStatus(ItemSellStatus.SELL);
        item.setStockNum(100);
        item.setRegTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        item.setUpdateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        Item savedItem = itemRepository.save(item);
        System.out.println(savedItem.toString());
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.maven_shopping</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven_shopping</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven_shopping</name>
    <description>maven_shopping project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
#port setting
server.port=80

#MySQL connect setting
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost::3306/shop?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****

#show query console
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

#query hibernate formatting
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#question mark parameter
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

##Thymeleaf cache ????
#spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
#spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop
spring.datasource.hikari.username=root
spring.datasource.hikari.password=****
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=TestHikariPool
```

application-test.properties :

```
# DataSource Setting
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

#h2 Database dialect Setting
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/jpashop;
    // MVCC=TRUE : 여러개의 요청이 들어왔을때, 빠르게 처리할 수 있도록 도와줌
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
      #애플리케이션 실행시점에 내가 가진 SQL문을 다 지우고, 다시 생성함
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        # System.out.println을 통해 sql문이 출력됨 -> 로그로 출력하게 해야함!
        format_sql: true
logging.level:
  org.hibernate.SQL: debug
  org.hibernate.type: trace
```

Comment: you seem to have 3 data sources in your application, 2 in application properties (one normal and one hikari) and a third one in application.yml. Is there any specific need for these?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).